# Deserialize a json string where name property is a number

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a web service that returns the following json

```
{
   "1": 1.654764367578323,
   "3": 1.654764367578323,
   "4": 1.654764367578323,
   "6": 1.654764367578323,
   "12": 1.13901127184207
}
```

In addition there might be 10 or 15 or 24 like below.  So I need to check if the following names are in the json string 1,3,4,6,10,15,24

```
{
   "1": 1.654764367578323,
   "3": 1.654764367578323,
   "4": 1.654764367578323,
   "6": 1.654764367578323,
   "10": 1.13901127184207
}
```

I want to deserialize the above json so I tried

```
dynamic d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonstring);
```

but I cannot do d.1 and get the value 1.654764367578323.

However, in the watch I get "End of expression expected"

Comment: are you able to change the web service?

Comment: :-( not able to change the web service

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207731/how-can-i-deserialize-json-to-a-simple-dictionarystring-string-in-asp-net

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can cast the object returned by JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonstring) to JObject and from there you can read values just like this.

```
JObject d = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
string value1 = d["1"].Value<string>();
```

Here is [Demo](http://dotnetfiddle.net/gOubcA)

You can always check whether returned JToken is null, it will be null if JObject is not able to find the property provided in indexer.

```
bool attributeExist = d[attribute] != null;
```

See [Here](http://dotnetfiddle.net/P1JlXg)

Comment: How do i check if the name attribute 10 exists in JObject d?

Comment: you can check like this -> bool attributeExist = d["10"] != null;

Answer (score 1):

Try d[12] instead. It depends alot on your Json libary though.